# Merge Multiple Multidimensional Array from foreach

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to join these multidimensional arrays.
I tried to use array_merge but it didn't work.

```
0: {
   0: {
      id: "121",
      slug: "btm-dc-402",
     },
   1: {
      id: "122",
      slug: "btm-dc-403",
      }
},
1: {
   0: {
      id: "493",
      slug: "jog-buah-401",
      },
   1: {
      id: "946",
      slug: "dps-buah-356",
      }
   }
```

Result that I expected like this.

```
   0: {
      id: "121",
      slug: "btm-dc-402",
     },
   1: {
      id: "122",
      slug: "btm-dc-403",
      }
   2: {
      id: "493",
      slug: "jog-buah-401",
      },
   3: {
      id: "946",
      slug: "dps-buah-356",
      }
   }
```

Could you please help.
Thank you

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far with `array_merge`?
`$arrMerged = array_merge($arr[0], $arr[1])` should work for your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    
$my_array = array(    
    0 => array(
        array(  
            "id"   => "121",  
            "slug"   => "btm-dc-402"  
        ),  
        array(  
            "id"   => "122",  
            "slug"   => "btm-dc-403"  
        ),  
    ),
    1 => array(
        array(  
            "id"   => "493",  
            "slug"   => "jog-buah-401"  
        ),  
        array(  
            "id"   => "946",  
            "slug"   => "dps-buah-356k"  
        ),    
    ),
);


$newArray = [];

foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $k => $v) {
        $newArray[] = $v;
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Demo - https://3v4l.org/D2pC0

Answer (score 1):

Another solution similiar to the accepted answer:

```
<?php

$my_array = array(    
0 => array(
    array(  
        "id"   => "121",  
        "slug"   => "btm-dc-402"  
    ),  
    array(  
        "id"   => "122",  
        "slug"   => "btm-dc-403"  
    ),  
),
1   => array(
    array(  
        "id"   => "493",  
        "slug"   => "jog-buah-401"  
    ),  
    array(  
        "id"   => "946",  
        "slug"   => "dps-buah-356k"  
    ),    
),
);

$newArray = [];

foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
     $newArray = array_merge($newArray, array_values($value));
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/LKiEM